# JQuery get radio button selection

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to use JQuery and Ajax to submit a group of forms.  The forms do not always have the same number of inputs or the same names to elements.

The code works fine for what I have with the exception of getting the values of which radio button is checked.  It always returns the value of the last radio button.

Here is how I am getting the form data:

```
var values = {};
var formdata = new FormData();
$('form :input').each(function()
{
    formdata.append(this.name, $(this).val());
});
```

I have also tried:

```
$('form.ajax :input, form.ajax input[type=radio]:checked').each(function()
```

What is the proper way to get the values of the checked radio button?  I am hoping not to have to write a separate function for each form that I submit.

Comment: I assume your radio buttons have a `name` property - so `$(":radio[name=yourName]").val()`

Comment: This way you take all inputs and because the radio buttons have the same name the value gets overwritten

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you can select all input elements other than checkbox and radio and then append the values of selected checkbox and radio elements

```
var values = {};
var formdata = new FormData();
$('form').find(':input:not(:checkbox, :radio)').each(function () {
    formdata.append(this.name, $(this).val());
});

$('form').find(':checkbox:checked, :radio:checked').each(function () {
    formdata.append(this.name, $(this).val());
});
```

Why don't you try the below instead of creating the formdata manually

```
var formdata = new FormData($('form')[0]);
```

Comment: Thank you.  The last line is exactly what I needed.  Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is iterating through all of the inputs (radio buttons included) and adding their name-value pairs into the form data. The problem is that if you have multiple radio buttons, you'll only see the last name-value pair, because all of the radio buttons have the same name.

In order to handle the radio buttons correctly, you need to check if `this.checked == true`, meaning this particular radio button is the checked one:

```
$('form :input').each(function()
{
    if (this.type == 'radio' && !this.checked)
    {
        // this is a radio button, but it's not checked, so skip it
        return;
    }
    formdata.append(this.name, $(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Works for me. You saved my night :) Thanx a lot.

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of each checked radio button on a page, simply loop through them, filtering only the checked radio inputs and run whatever code you want on each occurrence.

```
var formData = new FormData();

$('input[type=radio]').filter(':checked').each(function () {
    var inputField = $(this);
    formData.append(inputField.attr('name'), inputField.val());
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to serialize the list of selected radio buttons before you send via Ajax.

```
var radioChecked = $(":radio").serialize();
$.ajax(
        {
             url: _action_url,
             data: radioChecked,
             success: function(result){
                 // What do we do when success
             }
        }
        );
```